# Різниця між словами "для" та "задля"?

Tags: різниця-між-словами

Чи є якась різниця між цими словами? Наприклад:

> Катерина зробила цей вінок **задля** Марійки.
>
> Катерина зробила цей вінок **для** Марійки.

Яке значення взагалі має частинка *за* у слові *задля*?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

У [Академічний тлумачний словник (1970—1980)](http://sum.in.ua/s/dlja):

> ДЛЯ, прийм., з род. в.
>
> 1. Указує на особу, предмет і т. ін., заради яких що-небудь здійснюється, відбувається, яким що-небудь призначається. — Слухай, козаче, пісню русалки, — То ж я для тебе співаю! (Леся Українка, I, 1951, 329);
>      //  Указує на призначення предмета. Любов несе в руках невелике пуделко і стирочку, Орест — гіпсову головку і дошку для малювання (Леся Українка, II, 1951, 35);
> 2. Указує, з якою метою здійснюється, відбувається що-небудь. Раз у бабусі Шелестихи Я на тім тижні гостював І любим діткам для потіхи Химерну вигадку дістав (Леонід Глібов, Вибр., 1957, 281);).
> 3. Указує на особу, предмет, яких стосується названа обставина, якість і т. ін. Сиділи, руки поскладавши, Для них все празники були (Іван Котляревський, I, 1952, 149).
> 4. рідко. Указує на причину якоїсь дії. Для першої стрічі з панною Устею він їй дарує оці квіти (Михайло Коцюбинський, II, 1955

Там само:

> ЗАДЛЯ, прийм., з род. в., розм. Сполучення з прийм. задля виражають:
>
> Об'єктні відношення
>   1. Уживається при означенні особи, предмета, на користь яких щось здійснюється, відбувається. Настала весна. Старий розпочав нову хату будувати задля Якова, а про Йосипа — ні слова (Панас Мирний, IV, 1955, 42);
>   //  Уживається при означенні особи, предмета, в інтересах яких, заради яких щось здійснюється. — Задля неї, задля власного щастя лишився я, наважився перемогти себе... (Михайло Коцюбинський, I, 1955, 421);
>
> 2. Уживається при означенні особи, предмета, по відношенню до яких має силу, значення названа обставина, якість, стан і т. ін. Не співай повесні, Соловейко, мені.. Про щасливії дні, Що, мов наче вві сні, Задля мене минулися нині (Іван Манжура, Тв., 1955, 45);
>      Відношення мети
> 3. Уживається при визначенні мети дії. [Трохим (до косарів):] Ану, задля початку утніть пісні, розбудіть лугове птаство, щоб ховалось від гострих кос! (Марко Кропивницький, V, 1959, 130); 
>      //  Уживається при вказуванні на предмет, признач. для чого-небудь. Столи задля карт;
>      //  Уживається у складі сполучника мети. Широкоплечі стави та озера порозлягалися в затишних балках, по низах, мов задля того, щоб ясне сонце й синє небо повсякчас любувалися та видивлялися у їх чистих, прозорих водах (Панас Мирний, IV, 1955, 219).
>
> Причинові відношення
>
> 4. рідко. Уживається при визначенні причини якої-небудь дії або якихось вчинків. Маленька лампа на стіні задля браку чистого повітря майже погасала (Лесь Мартович, Тв., 1954, 315); .
>      Задля того — тому, з цієї причини. — Це, мабуть, ти задля того до мене такий добрий, щоб я одписав тобі, а не Уласові, хату та ґрунт (Нечуй-Левицький, III, 1956, 289).

Також, знайшла  інформацію у [Як ми говоримо](http://yak-my-hovorymo.wikidot.com/pryjmennyky):

> Прийменники для й задля часто виступають як синоніми: «Для тебе сина породила» (Т. Шевченко); «Задля нього зробила» (Г. Квітка-Основ’яненко);

Отже, вживаючи "для" і "задля" треба враховувти контекст.

Comment: Цей допис значно виграв би від скорочення цитат, у рази.